# Import .cmp file to webapplication

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, central-administration, import

I have exported my site with Central Admin to `.cmp`

Now I use `Import-spweb` to import it to another webapplication
like this :

```
`Import-SPWeb http://srvdev:7070/Linstance/ -Path C:\Bak\Linstance.cmp -`UpdateVersions Overwrite
```

After this, when I try to open `http://srvdev:7070/Linstance/`
I get an error message.

In the `\Listinstance.cmp.import.log` I can see that all the lists, pages, libreries are created.

Any idea?

Comment: What do the ULS logs for the correlation ID tell you?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee210652.aspx

Comment: i have to activate feature , the collaboration feature for publish site

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked features and I didn't find my feature actived. I had to activate them manually including the the team site collaboration feature.

So, I had to  activate the Team Site Collaboration feature and all the other features which are associated to the web before doing the import.

After this it works fine

Comment: Add those kind of notes as comments or edit your original question.